# Increase the width of SVG rect

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to increase the `width` of a `<rect>` while keeping the `height` unchanged?

**Use case:**
There are different `svg` shapes that contain text like the one in the below example. Depending on the inputs this text may change. If the text is too long, 
I want to increase the width to match the width of the text.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100"  width="300px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Hello World</text>    
</svg>
```

In the above example, the visible size of the `<rect>` is 300x100 pixels. 
If I want to keep the visible `height` and increase the `width`, 
I found that I can increase the `width` value of all `svg->width`, `svg->viewBox->width` and `rect->width` attributes.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 100"  width="400px" height="100px">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="100" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Hello World</text>    
</svg>
```

Could this go wrong?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Is the specified `viewBox` even necessary in your real scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVGs are amazing when it comes to filling the box that you give it. Simply create a div container with the required width and height styles and then put the svg inside of it set at 100% width and height. and do the same with each graphic element.

*Keep in mind that using this method means you will more than likly need to adjust the padding of the div to place the svg where you need it.*

```html
<div style="width:600px; height:150px;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Hello World</text>    
  </svg>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="width:100px; height:25px;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" stroke-width="3px" fill="white"/>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">Hello World</text>    
  </svg>
</div>
```